# is it possible to filter links of a wikipedia article in single query?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to make use of wikipedia API to retrieve links that has **Template:Persondata** embedded in it from an article in single call.

e.g. all people's articles that the article "George Clooney" links to.

as workaround:

1. I am getting the list of articles using **prop=links** param

   **http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=George_Clooney&pllimit=500&plnamespace=0&format=json**
2. then checking the templates of each article to see if it contains **Template:Persondata**.

   **http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=templates&titles=*article_title*&tllimit=500&format=json**

I know that by using **list=embeddedin** query we can get all articles of specific Template but it is used to filter all articles in Wikipedia.

is it possible to use something similar to filter a list of articles I am getting in step 1? or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that will give you a list of the links on the George Clooney page, and all the templates embedded in them. You can use this to pull out only the articles ones with Template:Persondata embedded.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=links&titles=George_Clooney&prop=templates&tllimit=500&format=json

Comment: thanks! I was trying using the generator but did n't use the limit correctly

Comment: How can we get the list of all links available in the 'See Also' section?